# Where are audio device files in OSX?

Tags: audio, filesystem

Probably because OSX uses different naming conventions for [devices files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) and because OSX uses [Core Audio](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/mac/audio-and-video.html) audio subsystem (not ALSA or OSS) there are no devices such as:

`/dev/sdp`
`/dev/audio`
`/dev/mixer`
`/dev/snd/*`

So, where are audio devices file in OSX?

Comment: Can you give some examples of the kinds of audio device files you wish to locate? Are you asking about Audio Unit, VST, or LADSPA files, for example?

Comment: Or are you asking about drivers for specific hardware or peripherals?

Comment: I've asked about device files for audio devices in OSX. I ment device files as described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file . Question was not about drives or some specific hardware.

Comment: @OleksandrBolotov, What are you asking? The first sentence of the wikipedia article reads: `In Unix-like operating systems, a device file or special file is an interface for a device driver that appears in a file system as if it were an ordinary file.`. Then you state that your question is not about that; it's a complete contradiction. I realize that your English is not perfect, so maybe you can't exactly translate what you might be trying to say [?].

Comment: I just wanted to know what does OSX have instead of /dev/dsp and I don't know how to ask it better.  I don't know who down-voted your questions but that wasn't me.

Comment: Alex's question and responses are spot on. One of the innovations of unix in 1970 was that every device appears as a file (in /dev). You could thus read and write to a device in a hardware independent way. So in this case you would expect to see something like /dev/audio for the system audio input/output, and perhaps variants on that if additional audio devices are present. To manage parameters like sample rate, a second device, like /dev/audioctl is provided in Unix. It seems that OSX is not sufficiently unix-like to have them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the Mac OS X Developer Library:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/AccessingHardware/AH_Family_Reference/AH_Family_Reference.html)

> The Audio family does not export device interfaces for applications to
>   access audio hardware directly. However, it does provide a device
>   interface that the Audio Hardware Abstraction Layer (Audio HAL) uses
>   to access drivers derived from the Audio family.

So I guess you need to find more information on "Audio HAL"

Answer (score 5):

Here are some suggestions.

If you are talking about Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL) devices, then the path is

```
/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/
```

By default there is one bundle there: on my Mac `iSightAudio.driver`, is the driver for the built-in webcam.

Other devices may use Kernel Extensions; bundles that end in `.kext`, are located in:

```
/System/Library/Extensions/
```

Comment: OPs question is about the visibility of devices as streams in a hardware/driver independent way in /dev or /devices or similar.

Comment: I had a clingy audio device called "Squirrels Audio" from airsquirrels. Even after following their uninstall guide at https://help.airsquirrels.com/support/solutions/articles/1000185639-how-do-i-uninstall-airparrot-2-from-my-mac-, it just wouldn't go away. Turns out their driver was hidden under `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL/` so this solution came in handy :)